# What are the significances of the contravariant and covariant four-momentum and their corresponding four-forces in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

In General Relativity, the four-momentum is defined as
$$p^r=\frac{dr}{d\tau}$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time. Here, we find that the contravariant index is used. However, I am confused on the differences between the contravariant and covariant components of the four-momentum and the corresponding four-force.

1. What is the physical significance of the corresponding covariant form $p_r$?
2. Can we define the contravariant and covariant four-force as  $F^r=\dfrac{Dp^r}{D\tau}$ and $F_r=\dfrac{Dp_r}{D\tau}$, respectively, where $D/D\tau$ is the covariant derivative? How can we interpret them in the context of General Relativity?